# saving and loading RNN hidden states in PyTorch

Tags: python, regression, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use an RNN network in PyTorch for regression task. In the training phase the model is learned. I want to use the trained model in testing phase. For this purpose I have saved the learned model by:

```
torch.save(learned_model, "model_path")
```

Then I can load the model again by:

```
loaded_model = torch.load("model_path")
```

For testing phase I must use this loaded model but I want to know what is the value of the first hidden state of the model? I can initialize the first hidden state by zero but I think maybe this is not correct. Is there any function other than torch.save which can return the last hidden state in the learned mode? Then I can restore that hidden state and use it as the first hidden state in the loaded model for testing phase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. As far as I understand you want to know the weights of the last hidden layer in the trained model, i.e. `loaded_model`. In that case, you can simply use model's `state_dict`, which is basically a python dictionary object that maps each layer to its parameter tensor. Read more about it from [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#what-is-a-state-dict).

```
for param in loaded_model.state_dict():
    print(param)
```

Sample output:

```
rnn.weight_ih_l0
rnn.weight_hh_l0
rnn.bias_ih_l0
rnn.bias_hh_l0
out.weight
out.bias
```

After that, you can get the weights of the last hidden layer using below code:

```
out_weights, out_bias = loaded_model.state_dict()['out.weight'], loaded_model.state_dict()['out.bias']
```